Lottie Animation library (.aar file) getting error: failed linking file resources in ATV11
I have integrated "lottie-6.4.0.aar" for using lottie library in my ATV11 Tv application. arr file was complied successfully but I try to use "LottieAnimationView" component like, " app:lottie_autoPlay" , "app:lottie_loop" & "app:lottie_rawRes". When this time app was not compiling it's shows following error,
vendor/apps/LottieSample/res/layout/dashboard_layout.xml:114: error: attribute 
lottie_autoPlay (aka com.sample.tv.lottiesample:lottie_autoPlay) not found.
vendor/apps/LottieSample/res/layout/dashboard_layout.xml:114: error: attribute lottie_loop (aka com.sample.tv.lottiesample:lottie_loop) not found.
vendor/apps/LottieSample/res/layout/dashboard_layout.xml:114: error: attribute lottie_rawRes (aka com.sample.tv.lottiesample:lottie_rawRes) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
18:26:07 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (31 seconds) ####

I have attached my Android.mk file for your reference,
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS  := optional
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE  := platform
LOCAL_SRC_FILES    := $(call all-subdir-java-files)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(call all-Iaidl-files-under, src)
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := LottieSample
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := lottie_api

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES := \
     androidx.appcompat_appcompat 

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES :=lottie_api:libs/lottie-6.4.0.aar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)

include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))

In Layout file I have mentioned like below,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_browse_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
      <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/lottieAnim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="false"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/animation_sample"/>
</LinearLayout>

App was compiled (using mm command) without "app:lottie_autoPlay", "app:lottie_loop" & app:lottie_rawRes. My doubt is if I need to mention any lottie library "res" into Android.mk file or else anything I missed to mention in mk or AndroidManifest.xml file.
Please help to solve this error thanks.

You should use LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES instead of LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES, and LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES instead of LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES
